# How to solve a equation with functions

Tags: equation-solving, functions

[image: Problem]

Hello, how would I be able to find the function for f(x) using Mathematica?
It should be f(x)=2x+1

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
f[x_] := a /. 
  Solve[{{a, b}.{3, -5 x} == x - 7, {b, a}.{3, -5/x} == 1/x - 7}, {a, 
     b}][[1]]
```

$f(x)=2x+1$. Hence $f(2010)=4021$

Comment: What does the b stand for in the code?

Comment: @TristanMa  `a` is f(x), `b` is f(1/x). Their roles reverse with $x\rightarrow 1/x$